# Constraints in ScrollView for centering and scrolling at the same time

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints, scrollview

I'm struggling with one case regarding autolayout using interface builder in xcode.

I want to adjust constraints in scrollview to:

1. Center view container inside UIScrollView when content view is smaller than scroll view.
2. Stick to the edges of content view inside scroll view when content view is bigger than scroll view. It should be scrollable.

I want to achieve that using one constraint setup without additional adjustments in code.

Is it possible? :-)

---

[image]

---

State 1: Centered

[image]

State 2: Scrollable

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by view container and content view? What's the relationship among container view, content view and the scrollview?

Comment: I've added layer structure image

Comment: So I guess the desired result is that the container view would never go off screen no matter how the scrollview is scrolled. Is it correct?

Comment: I just want to center view when it's small and scroll it when it's big :-) Nothing more.

Comment: Sorry I still couldn't get the picture though. Could you make some visual clarification on the two different state (content size is larger/smaller than scrollview)?

Comment: I've added new images. Hope it's clear now :-)

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a demo project if you missed it, hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Project demonstrating: https://github.com/Aquilosion/TestScrollViewConstraints

This is possible, although I've not been able to stop Xcode warning me that the constraints are incorrect (even though I'm pretty sure they're fine). What you need is:

1. Scroll View
2. Content View
3. Actual Content

I've made a test view controller to demonstrate this. The view hierarchy should look like this:

[image: View hierarchy]

My test view controller looks like this:

[image: View controller]

The blue area is the scroll view with the content view, and the white area is the "actual content" (with the label in it). If you enable multiple lines on the label, you get the following:

[image: View controller with multi-line label]

To get the effect, you need to lock the content view on all four sides to the view controller, and make it equal widths and equal heights. You need to modify the 'equal height constraint' so that it's 'equal to or more than 0', instead of the default 'equals 0'.

Meanwhile, in the 'actual content' view, you need to 'align Y' with its superview (the content view), and lock the top and bottom to its superview, but modify them again so that they are 'greater than or equal to' constraints. After that, it should stay central if too small, or expand properly when it gets bigger.

Comment: Your solution is working, but I can see red error regarding constraint setup inside interface builder. Is it possible to have it without this error?

Comment: @ArturOlszak I'm not sure; if anyone wants to have a look at the project to see if they can fix the constraints, I'd be interested in a solution. To be honest, I think it might be a bug in Xcode, as it works flawlessly at runtime without any errors reported.

Comment: That could be in fact a bug in Xcode. It's working great and there is no error messages at runtime. So big THX!

Answer (score 3):

The Best way to do this without any error is, set scrollViewInsets to your scrollview by calculating it according to screen height like below code ->

```
// ViewController.swift

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var scrollView : UIScrollView
    @IBOutlet var contentView : UIView


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    {
        let scrollViewBounds = scrollView.bounds
        let containerViewBounds = contentView.bounds

        var scrollViewInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        scrollViewInsets.top = scrollViewBounds.size.height/2.0;
        scrollViewInsets.top -= contentView.bounds.size.height/2.0;

        scrollViewInsets.bottom = scrollViewBounds.size.height/2.0
        scrollViewInsets.bottom -= contentView.bounds.size.height/2.0;
        scrollViewInsets.bottom += 1

        scrollView.contentInset = scrollViewInsets
    }


}
```

> For better understanding please refer below link
>
> Source -> https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/

Comment: I'm using FluentLayout in Xamarin.iOS and your solution works perfectly !!!